# How to declare a variable using another variable?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function in **C++** that can make a new **integer type variable** according to the name that has been provided

for eg

```
void my_variable(char name)
{
    int "something here" = 1;  // i am figuring out what to write 
    // there so that it makes a variable from that character that i have sent

    cout << "something here";
}
```

Comment: Local variable names only exist at compile time, so such a feature would have no use.  Perhaps you can explain your high-level goal?

Comment: Wrong language for this, you have picked.

Comment: preprocessor can do this with ## to join strings into whatever.

Comment: Maybe you like to define a class MyInt with a 'name' attribute in it?

Comment: well im sort of new to the language.. u know , still using the Borland Turbo C++.. I was kinda hoping that i could assign variables like these, in a game

Answer (score 4):

Look at using `std::map`. It allows you to create key-value pairs. The key would be `name` in this instance and the value would be the int. The following snippet shows you how to make a map, populate it, and then search for a value based on a key . . .

```
void my_function(std::string name)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> myMap;
    myMap[name] = 1;  // 

    cout << "Key " << name << " holds " << paramMap.find(name)->second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, `std::pair` allows you to *create* key-value pairs.  `std::map` allows you to *look up* pairs by the first half of their value.

Comment: `std::pair` allows you to create "first-second" pairs. The interpretation of `pair::first` as Key and `pair::second` as Value is specific to `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one posted it as an answer, sometimes it is convenient to define a macro to create a variable.

```
#define DEFINE_HELPER(x) Helper helper_##x = Helper(#x)
#define HELPER(x) (&helper_##x)

struct Helper {
    std::string name;
    Helper (const char *s) : name(s) {}
};

DEFINE_HELPER(A);
DEFINE_HELPER(B);

std::cout << HELPER(A)->name << std::endl;
```